# A function that maps draws from a gaussian to values between zero and one?

Tags: functions, special-functions

Simple question (I think).

Can you come up with a monotonically increasing function $f$ that map draws from a (standard normal) gaussian $x$~$N(0,1)$ to numerical values between zero and one, with the one requirement that $f(0)=1$?

The idea is that draws further from the mean, produces numbers that are closer to zero.

Thanks.

Comment: $$f(x)=1-|2\Phi(x)-1|$$ $$f(x)=4\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x))$$

Comment: Good idea to use the cumulative distribution function. It does the job. Thanks.